# Problem in exhibiting three graphics in Matlab in the same plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

For a project I receive data of two different pressure sensors: `P_mes` and `P_mes_new` and `Iem` in arrays. I have also an estimation of pressure value, which I call `P_est` and I also store it in an array. I want to plot all three arrays in the same plot, both as Y values, and as X I have a sample array which store the counter of a while loop.

When I try to plot `P_est` and `P_mes` X `samples`, it works. The way I'm doing is shown as follows:

```matlab
plot(grapheP,sample,P_est,'--b',sample,P_mes,'.r');
lgd_P=legend(grapheP, 'P_est','P_mes', 'Location','northwest');
lgd_P.FontSize=Fontsize;
```

But... When I add the third pair AKA `sample` x `P_mes_new` it generates an error. The code I'm trying is as follows:

```matlab
plot(grapheP,sample,P_est,'--b',sample,P_mes,'.r', sample, P_mes_new);
lgd_P=legend(grapheP, 'P_est','P_mes', 'P_mes_new', 'Location','northwest');
lgd_P.FontSize=Fontsize;
```

And the error I'm obtaining is:

```
Error using plot
Data must be a single input of y-values or one or more pairs of x- and y-values.

Error in UI (line 364)
    plot(grapheP,sample,P_est,sample,P_mes, sample, P_mes_new);"
```

Which it doesn't make any sense for me.

I would like to inform that I already tested doing the plot without the markers `'--b'` and `'.r'` but no success at all.

I also displayed the length of all these arrays to see if they don't have the size, as it follows, it has:

```
Length of sample: 1
Length of P_est: 1
Length of P_mes: 1
Length of pnew: 1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], we can't see the data in your variables so make a contained example where we can reproduce the error

Comment: what is `grapheP`? And what is `P_mes_new`?

Answer (score 0):

I can see in the code that you are using 3 variables as inputs in the plot before defining the line style, however, this is not a recommended way to do it. Instead, try to use one plot code line for each plot (each pair of variables), so you can have full control over the styles. Moreover, as Cris said, it would help to have screenshots of the resulting graphs and more information about the variables. The dimensions that you shared are not informative, or at least, it means that you have just 1 point per variable, so you will not see much.